# how do i assign these config variables from file in a bash loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have a configuration file with definitions like:

```
[BEGIN 1]
age=16
sex=M
height=1.5
weight=20
[END 1]
...
[BEGIN 4]
age=17
sex=F
height=1.3
weight=40
[END 4]
```

I  need to loop through these like so in another script:

```
worker_exec  $age  $sex  $height $weight -update | tee output.log
```

I was thinking if i only had one occurence in the config file i would remove the [BEGIN.. and [END.. lines and source it. But now there are multiple definitions, how would i read this file and get those definitions in bash variables and use them?
I also thought to use  temporary files, then it occured to me that extracting the N^(th) section
is something i dont know how to do with awk

End result is i can run

```
for item in ...# something here i dont get, maybe also unset any previous
               # definitions in previous loop if neccessary.
do
 worker_exec  $age  $sex  $height $weight -update | tee output.log
done
```

Comment: Are age sex etc just the number values ?

Comment: there are vars with strings, iv only given 4 but there will be more (maybe max ten)

Comment: I meant just the bit after the `=`. If not ill change my asnwer below

Comment: the variable age/sex is only assigned what appears immediately after the =

Comment: There is a time when you have to realize that shell may not have the power you need in order to do what you want. Shell has problems once you get more complex data structures. Both Python and Perl (which come on almost all Linux boxes) have modules that can easily read and manipulate this type of _INI_ style configuration file and handle all sorts of issues and edge cases you might not think of.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what you want this should work.

Awk to format it
Sets FS(Field Separator) to =
Sets ORS(Output Record Separator) to nothing

If it has `[END` on line print new line
If it does have `[END` or `[BEGIN` print line with a space(notice as ORS is nothing this does not print a new line)

Then just read through the lines as they are in the correct order the full line can be passed to worker_exec as it will be resolved prior

Triple redirect is used to pass variable into a loop.

```
VARS=$(awk 'BEGIN {FS="=" ;ORS=""};/\[END/ {print"\n"} !/\[END/ && !/\[BEGIN/ {print $2" "}' test)


while read line; do

     worker_exec $line -update | tee output.log

done <<< "$VARS"
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This will work with as many args as you have as long as they are passed in the right order to worker_exec

Comment: trouble is that the config file is hand written, there is no guarantee that items will be in the correct order, my script needs to do that, i did no mention that.

Comment: Even if it is hand written then surely you still want it to be consistent ? Do you want to values to be ordered before being put into lines ? Also wil the same amount of vars be in each begin end statement ?